# docker with device-mapper and luks

Tags: docker, luks

I'm trying to have docker container stored in a luks device, but using the below command it is not working.

I'm also trying to have a docker container to use (and maybe open) a luks file as a volume data, but I don't know how to bind it to the container

I have done the following :

```
pvcreate /dev/sdb
Physical volume "/dev/sdb" successfully created
vgcreate vgluks /dev/sdb
Volume group "vgluks" successfully created

lvcreate -l 90%FREE -n lvdocker-data vgluks
WARNING: crypto_LUKS signature detected on /dev/vgluks/lvdocker-data at offset 0. Wipe it? [y/n]: y
Wiping crypto_LUKS signature on /dev/vgluks/lvdocker-data.
Logical volume "lvdocker-data" created.

lvcreate -l 100%FREE -n lvdocker-metadata vgluks
Logical volume "lvdocker-metadata" created.
```

created a key

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/key bs=4K count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
4096 bytes (4.1 kB) copied, 0.00126301 s, 3.2 MB/s

cryptsetup luksFormat --batch-mode --key-file=/tmp/key /dev/vgluks/lvdocker-data 
cryptsetup luksFormat --batch-mode --key-file=/tmp/key /dev/vgluks/lvdocker-metadata

cryptsetup luksOpen --key-file=/tmp/key /dev/vgluks/lvdocker-data cryptfs-data
cryptsetup luksOpen --key-file=/tmp/key /dev/vgluks/lvdocker-metadata cryptfs-metadata
```

formated in ext4

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/cryptfs-data
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/cryptfs-metadata
```

my docker.service looks like this :

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
After=network.target docker.socket
Requires=docker.socket

[Service]
Type=notify
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// $OPTIONS
MountFlags=slave
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=1048576
LimitCORE=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and the **/etc/sysconfig/docker** is like :

```
OPTIONS="--storage-driver=devicemapper --storage-opt dm.datadev=/dev/vgluks/lvdocker-data --storage-opt dm.metadatadev=/dev/vgluks/lvdocker-metadata --insecure-registry myregistryhost:443 -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
```

The output of systemctl is :

```
systemctl status -l docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2015-12-23 16:05:28 CET; 25min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 6544 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 23 16:05:28 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Dec 23 16:05:28 localhost.localdomain docker[6544]: time="2015-12-23T16:05:28.457356524+01:00" level=warning msg="/!\\ DON'T BIND ON ANY IP ADDRESS WITHOUT setting -tlsverify IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING /!\\"
Dec 23 16:05:28 localhost.localdomain docker[6544]: time="2015-12-23T16:05:28.478448525+01:00" level=fatal msg="Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: Error running deviceCreate (CreatePool) dm_task_run failed"
Dec 23 16:05:28 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 23 16:05:28 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Dec 23 16:05:28 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Dec 23 16:05:28 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
```

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother. Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: unfortunately not, I didn't find a solution (but I stopped looking for one also)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the update.
I'm thinking about trying to stack btrfs on luks, mounting that to /var/lib/docker and using the btrfs storage driver on top of it.